# How many elements can an array store in unix script?

Tags: bash, unix, ksh, aix

How many elements can an array store in unix script (bash and ksh)? If limit is there how to increase the limit ?

Comment: if you need to ask this, you're probably doing something wrong!

Comment: What is your question here? Are you facing a problem to not to add elements to array? If so please state the necessary script with details

Comment: It is related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/43614890/5204037

Comment: I didn't get why this question got down vote, is this question wrong or repeated, please mention, any how I want the solution ...

Comment: Kindly don't increase anything; use an actual programming language such as Awk, Perl, Python, Php or many others...

Comment: Nonetheless I've checked bash-4/array.c: there's no explicit limit in it; it will fail when malloc/realloc runs out of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Pause a moment and re-think your question... This is not unlike asking how far can I drive? [what factors/variables come to mind that might influence this?]

The answer - it depends... In this case your hardware limitations, OS and shell configuration all impact your starting point; then, you may need to consider how your array is structured (i.e. long text strings or just numbers, etc.)

Also, there typically are both 'hard' and 'soft' limits with a Unix-type OS. For system, process and user 'limits' associated with Unix-like operating systems - review the man documentation and system settings for 'ulimit' for your target operating system(s). Also, the man documentation for the shell(s) you are using should also be reviewed since it may provide info on shell-specific limitations.

For each shell used on each OS used:  To confirm/determine any limits you should simply create a loop and note the 'array size' when your script crashes (complains about lack of resources).  Any 'limit' will be close to that number/size.  Set a max-threshold below this error-inducing-number then use a D&C (divide & conquer) approach when your data set exceeds your threshold...

:)
Dale